# Make side content float always in the center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

How can i make a  slide content always floating on the right side vertically centered? So that when the content is too long the slide will always be at the center?

Here's a screenshots.
[image]

Im using this jscrpt

```
<script>
                    function toggleDiv(divNum) {

                        $("#close").hide();
                        $("#center-content").removeClass("width-400px");
                        $("#right-content").animate({
                                right: '-400'
                            }, 350,
                            function() {
                                $("#center-content").addClass("width-400px");
                                $(".slide").hide();
                                if ($("#div" + divNum)) {
                                    $("#div" + divNum).show();
                                }
                                $("#right-content").animate({
                                        right: '0'
                                    }, 350,
                                    function() {
                                        $("#close").show();

                                    });
                            });
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#close").on("click", function(e) {
                            $("#right-content").animate({
                                right: '-400'
                            }, 350);
                            $("#center-content").removeClass("width-400px");
                            $(this).hide()
                        })

                    })
                </script>
```

And here's my CSS

```
.slide {
        width: 400px;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        #right: -400px;
        background: #6b4788;
    }
    #close {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        color: white;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-family: ovo;
        z-index: 10;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        font-weight: 100;
        padding: 43px 104px 34px 116px;
        background: #4d3065;
    }
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #main-content {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #right-content {
        position: absolute;
        right: -400px;
        top: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Html here to call:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-content">
    <div id="">
        <center>
            <div id="furugganan">
                <center><img src="furugganan-logo.png">
                </center>
                <div id="container">
                    <div id="firstrow">
                        <a onClick="toggleDiv(1)"><img src="alfonsoponce-a.png" id="alfonso">
                        </a>
                        <a onClick="toggleDiv(2)"><img src="female-a.png" id="female" style="margin-left: 30px;">
                        </a>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

And the right content:

```
    <div id="right-content">
                    <div id="close">CLOSE (X)</div>
                    <div class="slide" id="div1">
                        <center>
                            <img src="crest.png" style="
    /* z-index: -1; */
    opacity: 0.1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 39px;
    top: 371px;
    height: 354px;
">
                            <img src="sample-pic.png" style="height: 262px; margin-top: 12%;">
                            <h3>ALFONSO PONCE ENRILE</h3>
                            <hr style="width: 90px;margin-top: -7px;">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dui quam, feugiat ac metus vitae, egestas iaculis dolor. Aenean nec tempor tellus. Sed vehicula lorem et rhoncus dictum. Suspendisse potenti. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dui quam, feugiat ac metus vitae, egestas iaculis dolor. Aenean nec tempor tellus. Sed vehicula lorem et rhoncus dictum. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
                            <hr style="width: 90px;margin-top: 22px;">
                            <h1 style="margin-top: 30px;">LOREM: 1</h1>
                            <h1>LOREM: 2</h1>
                            <h1>LOREM: 3</h1>
                            <h1>LOREM: 4</h1>
                            <h1>LOREM: 5</h1>

                    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

/*This is the element which holding the side content
  by giving the property of overflow, it lets you 
  float the side element without affecting the content 
  flow*/

.container-of-side{    
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 950px; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.side{
    float: left;  /*then float the element*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the `#right-content` css position to `position:fixed;` and set 
body css  `{ overflow-x : hidden;}` fix the probeleme

please see bellow snippet :

```js
function toggleDiv(divNum) {
    //removing px word from width size
    if(slideWidth)
       slideWidth = slideWidth.replace("px","");
    else slideWidth=200;
    
    $("#close").hide();
    $("#center-content").removeClass("width-slide");
    $("#right-content").animate({right:-slideWidth},350,
    function(){
       $("#center-content").addClass("width-slide");
       $(".slide").hide();
       if($("#div"+divNum)) {
         $("#div"+divNum).show();
       }
       $("#right-content").animate({right:'0'},350,
       function(){
         $("#close").show();
         
       });
    });
}
var slideWidth = 200;
    
$(document).ready(function(){
   slideWidth = $("#right-content").css("width");
    
   $("#close").on("click",function(e){
      $("#right-content").animate({right:-slideWidth},350);
      $("#center-content").removeClass("width-slide");
      $(this).hide()
   })

})
```

```css
.slide {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  background:#d2d2d2;
}



#close {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  z-index:10;
  display:none;
}

body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

#main-content {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}

#right-content {
  position:fixed;
  right:-400px;
  top:0;
  #overflow:hidden;
  width:400px;
  height:100%;
}



#center-content {
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1000;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  transition:width .35s ease; /* here set the transition */
}

/*class to set width -200px*/
.width-slide {
  width: calc(100% - 400px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-content">
  <div id="center-content">
    <button onClick="toggleDiv(1)">Try it 1</button><div style="height:300px"></div>
    <button onClick="toggleDiv(2)">Try it 2</button><div style="height:300px"></div>
    <button onClick="toggleDiv(3)">Try it 3</button><div style="height:300px"></div>
    
  </div>
  <div id="right-content">
    <div id="close">X</div>
    <div class="slide" id="div1">content 1</div>
    <div class="slide" id="div2">hey I'm content 2</div>
    <div class="slide" id="div3">Now it's content 3</div>
  <div>
</div>
```